# Is it possible to setup Enigmail for Thunderbird, so that signatures are sent as attachments?

Tags: pgp, enigmail

In a PGP sign only email, I find that when I use Enigmail, the signature is part of the body of the email and is pretty painful to read on say a browser. I have seen others send signed email where the signature comes as an attachment. Is it possible to achieve this with Enigmail? How can it be configured in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Check the OpenPGP -> "Use PGP/MIME for this message" menu entry while composing the e-mail.

You can make this option permanent in the Edit -> Account Settings... menu entry.
Choose "OpenPGP Security" in all relevant accounts, and check the "Use PGP/MIME by default" option.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct...

Comment: Thanks, I joined this today. Good thing I only had 1 rep, then!
I agree this is probably a better fit at Super User, but since this is also a security-related question, I see why it was posted here, although I'm not sure where it's better.